# Unexpected output for simple std::map iteration in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I'm a bit stumped with, what I thought was, some simple code. It was previously working, so I wasn't sure why it stopped working. This is a single threaded program.

```
    Model *model;
    ModelMap::iterator model_map_iterator;

    cout << this->models.size() << endl;

    for( model_map_iterator = this->models.begin(); model_map_iterator != this->models.end(); model_map_iterator++ ){

        cout << "what" << endl;
        //model = model_map_iterator->second;
        //cout << *model;

    }

    cout << this->models.size() << endl;
```

And here's the output when there's 1, 2 and 4 models, respectively.

```
$ program
    1
    what
    1

$ program
    2
    what
    what
    2

$ program
    4
    what
    what
    4
```

As you can see, for any number of models greater than 2, the number of "what" outputs is 2. I've tried it for 2-5 models. All of them produce two "what" strings, yet output the correct size of the std::map.

Could anyone please help me find out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance...

**UPDATE:**

Committed entire codebase for debugging:

https://github.com/homer6/modeler/tree/crudepythonmodeler

commit ( 00c01ad634df70cc7f67efba96b1503ffd63529c )

it's the crudepythonmodeler branch

README.md contains the install steps for ubuntu

Comment: I doubt this is the problematic code.

Comment: I've checked it multiple times. And when I change the code, the output changes. This is certainly the problematic code.

Comment: Can you post the whole thing if it is not much bigger?

Comment: Just because the output changes when you change this code doesn't mean this code is the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's much bigger.

Comment: The bug is almost certainly in code you haven't pasted. You can start by testing with `valgrind`.

Comment: What could the problem be then?

Comment: @Homer6: We can't debug code we can't see. Most likely, the map is correct -- it could be a double free, access after free, access past bounds, access before bounds, or the like. Does `Model` follow the rule of three?

Comment: Did you write modelMap::iterator?

Comment: No, it's a typedef. This is open source. I'll commit the entire thing. One sec.

Comment: Added (above). Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: @Ben I've confirmed that it was an error with the iterator. Can you post an answer below and I'll mark yours as the accepted answer? Your comment is what triggered me to eventually find the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Homer6 No problem, i have added a brief answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is probably a problem with ModelMap::iterator. You may want to revise how this was written.

Comment: Ben help correct this error. See my answer for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer.

Here is the typedef for the ModelMap:

```
typedef ::std::map<Utf8String,Model*,Utf8StringComparator> ModelMap;
```

I had sloppily changed the signature in the Utf8StringComparator to return int instead of bool.

Thank you for looking into this. I'll confirm when I'm certain.

Comment: Confirmed. This was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the above code prints the results quoted, it is pretty clear that the `ModelMap` data structure got corrupted in some way. The corruption almost certainly took place before this function was called. How the map got corrupted exactly is impossible to tell based on the quoted code and data. The two most likely candidates are

1. The keys of some of values got changed (assuming the data structure is, indeed, a map).
2. The internal pointers got overwritten at some point.

I would probably guess the latter although this normally results in a crash rather than some partial output. A potential reason could be that the object being looked at happens to be destroyed object returned by reference from a function. However, this is all pretty much guesswork: To locate the error, you'd need to post more code, removing a lot of the irrelevant code as well (i.e., posting hundreds lines of code won't give you an answer where the problem is exactly, nor will the above code, however).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the entire codebase to github. I'll check it over for those specific errors too.

Comment: As I said, "posting hundreds lines of code won't give you an answer where the problem is exactly"!